# Reverse for 'send_form' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'app/send_message/(?P<flag>\\d+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a form to be used in 2 pages (index and contact).

Once the form performs method post, it will bring a page either success or failed (simple html page with few words).

I am stuck due to the error shown above and I’m still new in using Django.

Appreciate any help. Thank you

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls'))
]
```

app/url.py

```
from .views import *

app_name = "app"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^send_message/(?P<flag>\d+)/$', send_form, name='send_form'),
    url(r'^send_message/success/$', success, name='success'),
    url(r'^send_message/failed/$', failed , name='failed'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .forms import MessagesForm
from django.conf import settings
rom django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def home(request):
   empty_form = send_form(request)
   cover_title = PageServiceCover.objects.latest('id').title
   cover_text = PageServiceCover.objects.latest('id').text

   context = {'cover_title': cover_title, 'cover_text': cover_text,'form':empty_form}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def send_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            form.save()
            subject=[name, phone, category]
            send_mail(subject, text, email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('thanks', flag='success' )
        else:
            return redirect('not_working', flag='failed')

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html')

def failed(request):
    return render(request, 'notworking.html')
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'app:send_form' %}" method="POST" target="_blank">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit"> Send Message </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `send_form` url expects an argument named `flag` but you are not passing that. Also your `redirect`s won't work because you don't have URLs named `thanks` or `not_working`.

Answer (score 0):

Your url need a flag

```
url(r'^send_message/(?P<flag>\d+)/$', send_form, name='send_form'),
```

change view and pass flag from template

```
def send_form(request, flag):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            form.save()
            subject=[name, phone, category]
            send_mail(subject, text, email, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('thanks', flag='success' )
        else:
            return redirect('not_working', flag='failed')
```